# Trying to load a file into a database on virtual machine

Tags: postgresql, linux, postgresql-9.3, bulkcopy

I have set up a Postgres db on a linux vm and have been having no issues using a GUI to connect to it. However, I am trying to load a large, 32GB, file onto it and so am skeptical of the old way I was doing as it takes a lot of bandwith. I set up a dropbox folder to sync on the VM, which it has, and tried to COPY the file and got error message:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "~/Dropbox/0ptimus-Jaspin/nation/VoterMapping--NH--03-17-2014-HEADERS.tab" for reading: No such file or directory
```

I used the following to try to do the copy:

```
COPY nh FROM '/Dropbox/0ptimus-Jaspin/VoterMapping--NH--03-17-2014-HEADERS.tab';
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have `"~/Dropbox/...` in the 1st snippet and `"/Dropbox/...` in the 2nd. Perhaps this is the reason?

Comment: Tried both variations

Comment: In which directory is the file?

Comment: It would be Dropbox, would I have to move it to another one then?

Comment: My guess is that the user that Postgres run as, has not read access to the file or directory. Move the file to a directory that the postgres user has access or give specific access to the file (with `chmod`)

Comment: Gave postgres full rwx for Dropbox but still not working

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` doesn't understand the shell-script shorthand `~` for "my home directory". You must specify the path explicitly, e.g.

```
COPY nh FROM '/home/MYUSERNAME/Dropbox/0ptimus-Jaspin/VoterMapping--NH--03-17-2014-HEADERS.tab';
```

at which point you'll probably get a "permission denied" error, because `COPY` runs as the postgresql server user, which can't normally read files from user homedirs. If you're on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora then setting permissions won't be enough, you'll need to change SELinux rights too.

Instead, I suggest using `\copy` from `psql`.

```
cd ~
psql
\copy nh FROM 'Dropbox/0ptimus-Jaspin/VoterMapping--NH--03-17-2014-HEADERS.tab';
```